# Dancer framework

Tags: perl

При переходе по адресу http://localhost:3000/ открывается страница с ошибкой

> Warning caught during route execution: utf8 "xE9" does not map to Unicode at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Dancer/FileUtils.pm line 90, <$fh> line 83.

Возможно кто-то знает как исправить данную ошибку ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположительно, в каком-то файле, который оно читает, текст не в UTF-8. Возможно, или в CP-1251 («й») или в ISO-8859-1 («é»). Ищите выше по трейсбеку, что такое читалось, и разбирайтесь с этим файлом.

Comment: Padre у меня показывает, что все файлы в созданном проекте не utf8

Comment: Нашёл... В общем файл index.tt перекодировал в utf8 и всё заработало . Там был русский текст

Comment: А Dancer хочет UTF-8, судя из сообщения об ошибке.

В частности, например, из Dancer::Cookbook, секции «[Template and Unicode](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Cookbook.pod#template_and_unicode)»:

> If you use Plack and have some unicode problem with your Dancer application, don't forget to check if you have set your template engine to use unicode, and set the default charset to UTF-8.

Comment: Только вот не понятно почему изначально файлы не создаются в utf8 кодировке